# Multithreading in libgdx and loading assets

Tags: java, multithreading, libgdx

I am currently trying to make a loading screen for my libgdx game, but I am unsure how to do so. I think that I need to load all my data for the game and render the loading screen on separate threads, but I am unsure about how to create a new thread. Am I thinking about this wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets), which provides asynchronous asset loading. Actually there are a number of reasons why you might want to use an asset manager outside of having a loading screen.

The tutorial describes how to show a loading screen while you're loading your assets.

> So far we only queued assets to be loaded. The AssetManager does not yet load anything. To kick this off we have to call AssetManager#update() continuously, say in our ApplicationListener#render() method:
>
> As long as AssetManager#update() returns false you know it's still loading assets. To poll the concrete state of loading you can use AssetManager#getProgress(), which returns a number between 0 and 1 indicating the percentage of assets loaded so far. There are other methods in AssetManager that give you similar information, like AssetManager#getLoadedAssets() or AssetManager#getQueuedAssets(). You have to call AssetManager#update() to keep loading!
>
> If you want to block and make sure all assets are loaded you can call:
>
> `manager.finishLoading();`
>
> This will block until all the assets that have been queued are actually done loading. Kinda defeats the purpose of asynchronous loading, but sometimes one might need it (e.g. loading the assets needed to display the loading screen itself).

Comment: Thanks, Helped a lot!